# File r/w locking and unlink

Tags: unix, atomic, nfs, file-locking, fcntl

I have following problem. I want to create a file system based session storage where each session data is stored in simple file named with session ids.

I want following API: `write(sid,data,timeout)`, `read(sid,data,timeout)`, `remove(sid)`
where sid==file name, Also I want to have some kind of GC that may remove all timed-out sessions.

Quite simple task if you work with single process but absolutly not trivial when working with multiple processes or even over NFS.

The simplest solution I thought about was:

```
write/read:
   fd=open(file_name,O_CREAT | O_RDWR); // create a new file or use exsting
   fcntl_lock_file(fd)
   save data to fd/read data from fd
   fcntl_unlock_file(fd)
   close(fd)

GC:
   fd=open(file_name,O_RDWR);
   fcntl_lock_file(fd)
   if(timed_out)
      unlink(file_name)
   fcntl_unlock_file(fd)
   close(fd)
```

The biggest issue that file unlinking works on file names and file locks work on file
descriptors. So the above would not work in following scenario:

```
GC - open,
write - open
GC - lock, unlink, unlock, close // file still exists because held by write
write - lock, write, unlock, close // file removed
```

Does anybody have an idea how such issue may be solved? Are there any tricks that allow
combine file locking and file removal or make operation on file atomic?

**Notes:**

- I don't want to use Database,
- I look for a solution for Unix
- Solution should work with standard POSIX calls like fcnl, open, close, unlink

Thanks.

**Clearification** the major issue is that operation on files (names -- unlink) should be done atomically with operation of file descriptors -- locking:

- open, unlink -- work on files
- fnctl -- work on descriptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
write/read:
   fd=open(file_name,O_CREAT | O_RDWR); // create a new file or use exsting
   fcntl_lock_file(fd)
   if stat(file_name).{st_dev, st_ino} != fstat(fd).{st_dev, st_ino}
       unlock, close, retry
   save data to fd/read data from fd
   fcntl_unlock_file(fd)
   close(fd)
```

If `stat` fails with EEXIST (file name does not exist) or shows that the current file is not the same as the one you opened, bail.

Comment: I think this should work! Thanks a lot, this defenatly would connect the path and fd.